# where to put your image when using require to resolve image path [Vue]

Tags: image, vue.js, bootstrap-4

where do you copy the image in order for the following commands to work?

```
<b-img :src="require('../static/picture.jpg')" />

<b-card-img :img-src="require('../static/picture.jpg')" />
```

I got the following code from the vue bootstrap website [Vue Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/images/)

I wanted to try this out instead of making a lot of changes to the transformToRequire option.

---

partial directory layout for a vue project:

myProject | src | components (.vue files located in components directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path are relative to the file where you write your require.

So lets says the your script is in `./src/components/myComp.vue` your file would be lookup in `./src/static/picture.jpg`

The purpose of transformToRequire is not to manage asset location although it might issue error if path is not set properly. transformToRequire is only a syntactic sugar from `src="..."` to `src="require(...)"` and let webpack do the rest.

There is also an alternative if you don't want to border where your file is, especially when your are moving file around.

In webpack you set an alias for some path typically:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src')
    }   
  },
```

So that you can use:

```
<b-img :src="require(@/static/picture.jpg)" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Additional tip: it looks like (npm start) gives error messages if you capitalize the .JPG extension(?). `<b-img :src="require('../static/picture.JPG')" />` gives error messages but `<b-img :src="require('../static/picture.jpg')" />` or `<b-img :src="require('@/static/picture.jpg')" />` works great.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the structure you gave, you would have a `static` folder in `src` where you put your images.

But do note that `require` is relative to the currently file.